# How to match a substring from a cell from an array list in EXCEL

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, string

I'm trying to get a "Date" from the following column containing these values:

```
MODIFICATIONAUG16
NEWSEP16
RENEWALAUG 17
RENEWALAUG10
RENEWALAUG17
```

I want to extract the date part of these strings to make it look like:

```
AUG16
SEP16
AUG10
AUG17
```

Now these values do change depending on the what month it is so it could be anywhere between "JAN - DEC"

I've tried a Vlookup + Match function but cannot get the desired results.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are the month and year always going to be at the end of the string? In your example data, each string ends with either MMMYY or MMM YY, are those the only two possible formats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for all your supplied references:

```
=RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""),5)
```

[image]

Comment: YES! THANK YOU THIS WORKED can you explain please, I'm curious to see how this actually works.

Comment: @ChristianDiaz we are simply returning the last five characters without any spaces.  We substitute any spaces with nothing.